# Best place/way to declare static data in React

Tags: reactjs, class, variables, render

I am reading through the internet trying to find some performance resolute or preferred method of declaring static data, variables in react so I would like to hear your opinion.

This goes for react stateless and class components.

Let’s say I have an array with colors that I want to use somewhere inside React `return()`.

```
const colors = ["red, "green", "blue"];
```

1) Declare it inside of `render()`

I suppose this is not preferred, snce it will be recreated on every render.

2) Declare it in constructor as a global variable

```
this.colors = ["red, "green", "blue"];
```

Nice, but maybe not preferred in some cases to have global variables.

3) Declare it as a return of function placed inside React component but outside of `render()`. We call the function from React `return()`

4) I think I saw somewhere using defaultProps.

Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 14):

Few common approaches are to

> declare it above a class or in beginning of a file after imports

if its a file specific constants.

```
const CONST1 = [0,1,2,];

class xxx extends yy {
 ....
}
```

or you can keep it in seperate file and import it when its common to many places.

something like

> a json file

file a.json

```
{
 "color": "red"
}
```

usage b.js

```
 import constant from 'constants/a.json';

 console.log(constant.color);
```

or even in `global.color = 'red'` which i would not advice to use

Answer (score 4):

For class components, I've used the approach of declaring static variables on the class recently.

```
import React from 'react';

class Example extends React.Component {
  // never changes, but may be used in other places, such as parent components
  static displayName = 'Example';

  state = {
    someStateData: 'World'
  };

  render() {
    const { someStateData } = this.state;
    // do work
    return <p>Hello {someStateData}</p>;
  }
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: how about for a function component?

Comment: @ShankarS You can use `useRef` hook for the same purpose in function components.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think it depends on your needs, most cases 2 and 3 might be enough. I've seen several proyect sources (such as create-react-app, react-native-maps, for instance) and they all handle this consts and "Global resources" in a same way:

They put them in separated files, and they import them as modules in every file where they are needed. I've used this approach and I can tell you is a really good and common practice

Answer (score 0):

I want to bring up this because it's a really good thing:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactn

`ReactN` is a extension of React that includes global state management. It treats global state as if it were built into React itself -- without the boilerplate of third party libraries.

You can use `[ global, setGlobal ] = useGlobal()` to access the entire global state object.

It works in class, function, and non-react files.
I use it since 2 or 3 years ago, without a glitch.

I know that, given the OP's question, this is overkill. But anyway, I wanted to draw attention into this excellent tool.